# Why is [ɚ] used instead of [əɹ] in IPA phonetic transcriptions of English words?

Tags: ipa

Is there any pronunciation difference between both? Shouldn't IPA use one symbol per phonem/allophone? Curiously, this happens with the schwa, but not with "true" vowels, eg the A in car [kɑɹ].

Answer (score 4):

Most Americans do not pronounce [əɹ] with two different, consecutive sounds (phones), but with one phone. You say "Shouldn't IPA use one symbol for phoneme?" The problem is that [əɹ] is two symbols for one phoneme. So [ɚ] is used instead.

For the other r-colored vowels, many Americans use single phones for [ɑ˞] and [ɔ˞], but many also use two, so [aɹ] and [ɔɹ] are considered to be adequate IPA representations of these. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-colored_vowel#Examples) says:

> In words such as start, many speakers have r-coloring only in the coda of the vowel, rather than as a simultaneous articulation modifying the whole duration. This can be represented in IPA by using a succession of two symbols such as [ɑɚ] or [ɑɹ], rather than the unitary symbol [ɑ˞].

For the other three r-colored vowels, [ɛɹ], [ɪɹ], and [ʊɹ], even fewer use a single phone than for [ɑɹ] and [ɔr]. (In fact, I don't know whether any Americans use a single phone for [ɛɹ] and [ɪɹ].)

If you try to represent American and British speech with the same IPA symbols, you run into big problems. What vowel do you use for *palm*, *box*, *cloth*, *caught*? Those are two vowels in American and three vowels in British speech, and there's not any easy way to deduce the American pronunciation from the British, and vice versa. So why not use [ɚ]?

And the American pronunciation of *wanderer*, /ˈwɑn.dɚ.ɚ/, is indeed different from the British pronunciation, /ˈwɒn.dər.ə/, in the *der* syllable.

Comment: Three vowels in AmE as well if you don’t have the _cot–caught_ merger. (Also there’s no reason to assume that /ər/ is one phoneme. It may be pronounced as a single sound, a rhotacised schwa, but that doesn’t mean it’s not phonemically a sequence of two phonemes.)

Comment: You mean *palm* and *box* are different vowels? Or *cloth* and *caught* are different vowels? They're not for me.

Comment: Yes, _palm_ /ɑ/, _box_ and _cloth_ /ɔ/, and _caught_ /ɒ/ (to give phonemes – the /ɒ/ phoneme in particular varies a lot in actual pronunciation). Also to some AmE speakers, I’m pretty sure all four words would have /ɑ/. Can’t think off the top of my head right now which merger that would be, but one of ‘em.

Comment: The dictionaries say that [*palm*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/palm) and [*box*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/box) have /ɑ/ and [*cloth*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cloth) and [*caught*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/caught) have /ɔ/. Which matches my dialect. If you merge *cot* and *caught*, they all get the same phoneme. I don't know what dialect you're speaking, but are you sure that some British English didn't get mixed in?

Comment: @PeterShor The cot/caught merger is not binary.  _Palm_ has /ɔ/ on a lot of the East Coast. But I have heard it pronounced with /ɑ/    by people from Upstate New York who pronounce _caught_ with /ɔ/. When I try to put a /ɑ/ between "p" and "l" I wind up with a coughing fit. Or it comes out as /æ/. I don't know how they do it.

Comment: I really cannot perceive a difference between my pronunciation of after ( [æftər] ) and the Wiktionary/Cambridge dictionary audios of [æftɚ]. When going directly from [t] to some kind of [r] , my mouth unavoidably quickly passes through the uncolored schwa first. I'd teach the pronunciation of this word  syllabically as [æ] - [ftə] - [r]. From what you're saying, this is not how Americans speak. Same applies for first ([fɜrst] and [fɝst]).

Comment: @AlanEvangelista:  Can you hear the difference between the two pronunciations of *anorak* in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anorak)? Let me add that  [fɜrst] and [fɝst] are allophones in American English, so people would tend not to notice the difference, and for being understood, it doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Like Peter Shor, I think you may have mixed up different dialects. Most American English speakers, regardless of whether they have the cot-caught merger, have lost /ɒ/ as a phoneme distinct from "thought" and /ɑ/. I can't even think of any American accent with three phonemes in this area. Accents with two phonemes do differ in which words they assign to which category, but within an accent of American English there's typically not a three-way distinction between /ɑ/, /ɔ/, and /ɒ/.

Comment: @sumelic: I do agree with Spencer that the vowel in *palm* (and *balm, calm*, etc.) varies a lot on the East Coast. I probably should have used *spa* for the example word in my comment. And I am positive that some people in New York City have three different vowels in *horror, aura,* and *ford*, but that's not a typical American English accent (and the majority of them probably only have two).

Comment: @sumelic New Yorkers, as Peter mentions, were what I had in mind for the /ɒ/-like phoneme. I have definitely heard New Yorkers pronoun the vowel in _box_ and _cloth_ ([ɔ]) differently from the one in _caught_ (something like [oə] or even [uə]). I can’t say for sure whether these people pronounced _palm_ with [ɑ] or [ɔ] (which would make it only two vowels again), but if we use _spa_ or _father_ instead, there’s less variation. I’ll admit my “if you don’t have the _cot–caught_ merger” conditioning wasn’t very accurate, though.